# Thumbnail error occurred in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, thumbnails

I am doing code with these steps for getting youtube video thumbnail. Thumbnail url is printing but also I am getting an error mentioned below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! VideoAdsCell
    let youtubeId = extractYoutubeIdFromLink(link: arrayVideo[indexPath.row].video)

    if let url = URL(string: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/\(youtubeId!)/1.jpg") {
        print(url)

        let thumbnail = getThumbnailFrom(path: url)
        print(thumbnail as Any)

        cell.imageForMain.image = thumbnail
        cell.viewForMain.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cell.viewForMain.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    return cell
}
```

I am using this function for the video thumbnail. But I am getting the error.

**Image url:** http://img.youtube.com/vi/XHEa9Zu9qsc/1.jpg

**Error:** Error generating thumbnail: Cannot Open

```
func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path , options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return thumbnail

    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: if its a video you should use  AVAssetImageGenerator else you need to download and display the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `youtube` API that is not giving you video thumbnail url?

I can see the URL you're passing to getting the thumbnail is already a thumbnail url so you don't need to do anything extra. The reason is of your error is same you're passing an image url to `AVURLAsset` which expects a video url instead. So it can not be open.

You just need to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or any other third party library to showing the image on `imageView`. It handles the cache and asynchronous downloading itself.

Example of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage):

```
cell.imageForMain.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/\(youtubeId!)/1.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never supply a network URL to an initializer that should use resources fetched from that URL. Network requests are supposed to be executed asynchronously, while initializers must return in a synchronous manner, so you're asking for trouble when supplying remote URL's to methods that expect a local URL.

Moreover, there's no need for an `AVURLAsset` if you simply want to download an image and display it as a `UIImage`. You can simply use `URLSession.dataTask` to download the image.

You can use this `UIImage` extension to download an image asynchronously:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func downloadFromRemoteURL(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?,Error?)->()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil,error)
                }
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(image,nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then use it to get the thumbnail image like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! VideoAdsCell
    let youtubeId = extractYoutubeIdFromLink(link: arrayVideo[indexPath.row].video)

    if let url = URL(string: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/\(youtubeId!)/1.jpg") {
        print(url)
        UIImage.downloadFromRemoteURL(url, completion: { thumbnail,error in
            guard let thumbnail = thumbnail, error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            cell.imageForMain.image = thumbnail
            cell.viewForMain.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
            cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowRadius = 1
            cell.viewForMain.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            cell.viewForMain.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is working but the thumbnail is coming in blur type.

Comment: In that case the settings for your `layer` are flawed. The image itself is simply downloaded using `UIImage.downloadFromRemoteURL`, there's no modification applied to is. I'd suggest you open a new question for fixing the look of the image, since that's a different question than the issue you had in this one. You should also include screenshots of the expected/actual look of the thumbnail.